# Restrict access to localhost when using port-forwarding in K8s env

Tags: kubernetes, server, portforwarding

I have a HTTP server running in a pod in K8s environment. The server exposes 4 endpoints. Now what I want is to restict one of those 4 APIs if the user is using port-forwarding to access the endpoints on  localhost. Essentially, I dont anyone('kubeclt' user) to access a certain endpoint via port-forwarding.

I was thinking of implementing a middleware in code which would intercept and reject calls to that ndpoint based on the URL but that also blocks all the calls when someone directly `kubectl exec` into  the pods and directly use curl which I don't want. (*Can we figure out if the user has port-forwarded from inside the pod?*)

I was wondering if there is a way this could be done?
Any suggestions would be appriciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi `ray an` are your queries addressed revert back here if you are still having some queries, so that we can assist you..

Comment: Hi @KranthiveerDontineni. Appreciate your help. But what I am looking for is to restrct traffic to just one endpoint and not all of them. RBAC does not help me achieve that. Please corret me if I am wrong.

Comment: RBAC is required for preventing other users from editing your resource and do port forwarding as you said you are blacklisting the local traffic using some middleware I didn't mentioned about network policies using which you can restrict the traffic to a particular endpoint. If you need more details go through this [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/). Restricting traffic and blocking users from accessing your pods are different issues. we gave answers based on `Can we figure out if the user has port-forwarded from inside the pod?`

Comment: I am not sure if we can restrict the traffic to a particular endpoint using network policies. Apologies maybe my question was not very clear. 
Let me rephrase it - I want users to access a certain endpoint (and only that one among 4 endpoints) only when they exec into to pod. But they should not be able to access it if they are using the port-forward command. So, my question was how I can figure out from inside the pod that the user has port-forwarded? not sure how RBAC allows me to restrict one of those 4 APIs.

Comment: Like we said RBAC will prevent the users to use exec command on your container or pod and if you deploy your containers in separate namespaces you can use network policies to restrict traffic for a particular endpoint using the `CIDR` and `except` section mentioned in the official docs provided above.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show the code that you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Port forwarding control can be achieved by using on Kubernetes built-in RBAC(Role Based Access Control). You can give or revoke access for users to be able to use port-forwarding at first place.

Here is an example below, which grants such access and can be removed:

```yaml
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  name: port-forward-access
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/portforward"]
  verbs: ["create"]
```

see: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/110999

---

> restrict one of those 4 APIs

However, as you are asking to *restrict one of those 4 APIs*, I must say that this is the application which is exposing those endpoints, which should be configured on the application side to allow only partial traffic, say localhost only. I will recommend not to complicate things by trying to achieve that using Kubernetes.

One key thing to keep in mind that a pod is considered the smallest unit in the object model of Kubernetes. So complete what is operating inside and only expose what can be exposed.

Also, consider looking into service mesh or a sidecar container as the gateway to the actual application, if it cannot be achieved from within your said HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

The middleware might be able to restrict the traffic flow but cannot restrict the users from accessing the pods or resources etc. If you can control **RBAC** and your **security context controls** using the middleware it might help.

Using [**RBAC(Role Based Access Controls)**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/rbac-good-practices/) you can have a control on who should access which resource, users who are not having enough privileges cannot access or edit your resources even if they are cluster admins.

The following is the manifest example for configuring RBAC taken from the [**kubernetes official documentation**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#restrictions-on-role-creation-or-update)

> ```
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> kind: ClusterRole
> metadata:
>   name: role-grantor
> rules:
> - apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
>   resources: ["rolebindings"]
>   verbs: ["create"]
> - apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
>   resources: ["clusterroles"]
>   verbs: ["bind"]
>   # omit resourceNames to allow binding any ClusterRole
>   resourceNames: ["admin","edit","view"]
> ---
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> kind: RoleBinding
> metadata:
>   name: role-grantor-binding
>   namespace: user-1-namespace
> roleRef:
>   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
>   kind: ClusterRole
>   name: role-grantor
> subjects:
> - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
>   kind: User
>   name: user-1
> ```

If you want to add an additional layer of security restrictions in your pod security context you can use `AppArmor` for restricting the programs from making changes and `readOnlyRootFilesystem` option for restricting access to change your config file from within the pod. These will help you in preventing the attackers from modifying your configs using the programs deployed within the pod. The following is the manifest example for setting security context in kubernetes taken from [**official documentation**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/).

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: security-context-demo
> spec:
>   volumes:
>   - name: sec-ctx-vol
>     emptyDir: {}
>   containers:
>   - name: sec-ctx-demo
>     image: busybox:1.28
>     command: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 1h" ]
>     volumeMounts:
>     - name: sec-ctx-vol
>       mountPath: /data/demo
>     securityContext:
>       readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
> ```